IndexError: list index out of range in for loop while appending to list
I am trying to combine the first and last items in a list. For example, in a 10 item list, it would have items 1 and 10 combined, items 2 and 9 combined, items 3 and 8 combined, etc. (I am aware that in actual python it would be items 0 and 9, items 1 and 8, etc.)
This is my code to do this:
for x in range(len(numlist)):
    sortlist.append(str(numlist[x]) + "," + str(numlist[len(numlist) - x]))

However, it always gives this error message:
IndexError: list index out of range
When I try using global numlist inside the for loop, it says this:
SyntaxError: name 'numlist' is used prior to global declaration
Why is this?

I think some of the context around this code is needed.  For example, what is in numlist ?

numlist[len(numlist) - x] when x=0 is len(numlist) which is out of range. Change it to numlist[len(numlist) - 1 - x]

@Elerium115 That worked! Thanks!

You are trying to access the last element with the first iteration on x, so x = 0.
To fix this problem you can subtract 1 from the length of the list:
numlist = list(range(10))
sortlist = []

for x in range(len(numlist)):
    sortlist.append(str(numlist[x] + ',' + str(numlist[len(numlist)-x-1]))

print(sortlist)


You don't need append. Just use one lines.

You could not use an index counter at all and zip the list to itself in a comprehension, with slicing.
>>> var = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
>>> [''.join(x) for x in zip(var, var[::-1])]
['ah', 'bg', 'cf', 'de', 'ed', 'fc', 'gb', 'ha']

